# Java Graph Traversal: How to only obtain nodes in certain range?

Tags: java, range, breadth-first-search

I need to from a start node find the nodes that are n hops away and only from the start node. Also, the nodes n hops away can be in 3 directions from start node (A,B,C) and each subsequent node in 3 directions and so on. I have tried a BFS type algorithm : i.e:

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList();
queue.add(this.rootNode);
printNode(this.rootNode);
rootNode.visited = true;
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Node node = (Node)queue.remove();
    Node child=null;
    while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(node))!=null) {
        child.visited=true;
        printNode(child);
        queue.add(child);
    }
}
```

but its traverses all nodes from one to the next.
I was also thinking of using the Dijkstra algorithm but it computes *distances* from each node to the next, not hops and finds the shortest from one node to another. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a HashMap which stores the hops to parent nodes. For the root node, the value will be zero. Then, for every child, hop value will be 1 + hop-for-parent.

```
int k = 5; // Max number of hops.
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hops = new HashMap<>(); // to maintain hops
hops.put(this.rootNode.data, 0);  // hops to root = 0

Queue queue = new LinkedList();
queue.add(this.rootNode);
printNode(this.rootNode);
rootNode.visited = true;
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Node node = (Node)queue.remove();

    // Stop when queue has node with k number of hops. 
    if(hops.containsKey(node.data) && hops.get(node.data) == k){
         break;
    }

    Node child=null;
    while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(node))!=null) {
        child.visited=true;
        printNode(child);
        queue.add(child);

        // Child's hops = parent's hops + 1
        hops.put(child.data, hops.get(node.data) + 1);
    }
}
```

Considerations

- Key type of hops HashMap should be same as Node's data type.
- You can internalize the hops tracking, by adding int hopCount variable with Node class itself. Pollutes the Node class but makes overall code much cleaner.

Comment: does this take into consideration that the nodes n hops away can be in in any direction (preferably 3) from start node? I should specify that as well.

Comment: above code assumes the starting node as root. If starting node is an intermediate node, then, run the algorithm for whole tree starting from root (remove the if statement which has break;), find hops value of that intermediate node (say, it is 6), then print all its parent nodes until (6 - k) and all its children nodes until (6 + k).. this will give nodes in range for that intermediate node.

Comment: could you please select as answer, if satisfied with the code. Hope it helped